# How to add additional data into join table for has_and_belongs_to_many relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two tables `users` and `providers` that have has_and_belongs_to_many relationship.  The join table `providers_users` has an extra column `uid` in addition to `user_id` and `provider_id`.

How do I add a new record consisting of `users.id`, `providers.id` and `uid`?  I can add `users.id` and `providers.id` but can't figure out how I can add `uid`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.  If you want to add attributes to the join table, you need to make into a model, and then use :through on the relationships to achieve the same thing (this is actually my favorite way of implementing habtm relations):

```
class ProviderUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :provider

  validates_presence_of :uid
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :provider_users
  has_many :providers, :through=>:provider_users
end

class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :provider_users
  has_many :users, :through=>:provider_users
end
```